# Using Haskell to output a UTF-8-encoded ByteString

Tags: unicode, haskell, io, ghc, bytestring

I'm going out of my mind trying to simply output UTF-8-encoded data to the console.

I've managed to accomplish this using `String`, but now I'd like to do the same with `ByteString`. Is there a nice and fast way to do this?

This is what I've got so far, and it's not working:

```
import Prelude hiding (putStr)
import Data.ByteString.Char8 (putStr, pack)

main :: IO ()
main = putStr $ pack "čušpajž日本語"
```

It prints out `uapaj~�,�`, ugh.

I'd like an answer for the newest GHC 6.12.1 best, although I'd like to hear answers for previous versions as well.

Thanks!

Update: Simply reading and outputting the same UTF-8-encoded line of text seems to work correctly. (Using `Data.ByteString.Char8`, I just do a `putStr =<< getLine`.) But packed values from inside the .hs file, as in the above example, refuse to output properly... I must be doing something wrong?

Comment: What platform are you on?  Unicode on UNIX-like platforms works quite well now; Windows support is lagging a bit.  See the documentation for System.IO: "(GHC note: on Windows, we currently do not support double-byte encodings; if the console's code page is unsupported, then localeEncoding will be latin1.)"

Comment: 64-bit Linux. Doesn't `System.IO` work only with `String`?

Comment: You should not use `BS.Char8`, because that one assumes 8-Bit encoding and truncates multi-byte Unicode characters. Use normal ByteStrings unless you absolutely *know* that `BS.Char8` is the right data type (that includes knowing why normal ByteStrings are explicitly not the right type for that use case).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`utf8-string` supports bytestrings.

```
import Prelude hiding (putStr)
import Data.ByteString.Char8 (putStr)
import Data.ByteString.UTF8 (fromString)

main :: IO ()
main = putStr $ fromString "čušpajž日本語"
```

Answer (score 22):

`bytestrings` are strings of bytes. When they're output, they will be truncated to 8 bits, as it describes in the documentation for `Data.ByteString.Char8`. You'll need to explicitly convert them to utf8 - via the `utf8-string` package on Hackage, which contains support for bytestrings.

---

However, as of 2011, you should use the `text` package, for fast, packed unicode output. [GHC truncating Unicode character output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655544/ghc-truncating-unicode-character-output/5655601)

Your example becomes a lot simpler:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import qualified Data.Text    as T
import qualified Data.Text.IO as T

main = T.putStrLn "čušpajž日本語"
```

Like so:

```
$ runhaskell A.hs
čušpajž日本語
```

Comment: Doesn't utf8-string work only with Strings, and not ByteStrings?

Comment: No, it also works with bytestrings.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086842/using-haskell-to-output-a-utf-8-encoded-bytestring/2089195#2089195

Answer (score -2):

[This is a known ghc bug, marked "wontfix".](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/1079)

Comment: Noooooooo. :( But, I'm puzzled... it seems to work fine with regular Strings?

Comment: Whatever this is, it's fixed now. Executing the example given on your linked page works as expected. The difference is that I'm trying to output UTF-8-encoded ByteStrings, and not UTF-8-encoded Strings, which is supposed to be more efficient. Keep in mind I'm currently using GHC 6.12.1, although I know the problem doesn't exist in GHC 6.10.4 either.

Comment: No, that's not actually the problem. GHC 6.12 does utf8 *String* IO, if the locale is set to that. Which in fact solves the above bug, which isn't the problem the OP is asking about.