# Using Haskell's Parsec to parse a ByteString

Tags: haskell, parsec, bytestring

I've managed to use Parsec to parse a String, but cannot manage to do the same with a ByteString.

How can I make Parsec work with ByteStrings without manually converting them to Strings?

I get the feeling this isn't hard to accomplish. Am I wrong? (I'm new to Haskell. ^^)

Thanks!

Comment: Based on [the other question][1] you asked, you should learn to read the documentation of the library you're using. It's available on Hackage.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086842/using-haskell-to-output-a-utf-8-encoded-bytestring

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just import the `Parser` type from [`Text.Parsec.ByteString`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.0.0/doc/html/Text-Parsec-ByteString.html) or [`Text.Parsec.ByteString.Lazy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.0.0/doc/html/Text-Parsec-ByteString-Lazy.html), instead of from [`Text.Parsec.String`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.0.0/doc/html/Text-Parsec-String.html).

Comment: What is numbers in Text.Parsec.ByteString.Lazy(http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.0.0/doc/html/Text-Parsec-ByteString-Lazy.html)?

Comment: see (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455084/matching-bytestrings-in-parsec?rq=1)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455084/matching-bytestrings-in-parsec?rq=1] for where to go from here

Answer (score 2):

the answer actually depends on the version of Parsec you are using. If you are using version 3.0 or later then yes. For version 2.x.x I don't think you can.

http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.0.1/doc/html/Text-Parsec-ByteString.html

Cheers

edit: The Parsec that STH suggest (Text.Parsec.ByteString) is actually version 3.0 the previous version 2.x.x is located in Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.

Comment: Oh, then I seem to currently lack the newest version, and have been using the older one. I will upgrade. Thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

```
import Text.Parsec.ByteString ()
```

will give you the instance

```
forall m. Stream ByteString m Char
```

hence if you use, instead of `Parser a`:

```
p ::  Stream s m Char => ParsecT s u m a
```

Comment: were you trying to explain how to get Word8 instead of Char, by any chance. I can't figure that out.